# Perfect Pairing and submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring and $A, B, C$ be given $R$-modules such that we have a perfect pairing 
$$
\phi: A \times B \rightarrow C
$$
ie $A \simeq \text{Hom}_R(B,C)$.

If $A^\prime$ is a given submodule of $A$, is there an explicit description for the corresponding $B^\prime$ such that $A^\prime \times B^\prime \rightarrow C$ is a perfect pairing?

Comment: Use $B\cong\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,C)$ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may as well identify $A$ with $\hom_R(B,C)$ and think of the pairing as simply function evaluation,

$*:\hom_R(B,C) \times B \to C$

where $f*b=f(b)$.  Now a submodule $A'$ is just a subset of maps $f:B\to C$. To be a perfect pairing under restriction would now mean that $A'\cong \hom_R(B',C)$.  Take $B'=B/\cap_{f\in A'} \ker f$.  Each $f\in A'$ factors through $B'\to C$ which gives a natural map $A'\to \hom_R(B',C)$.  This map is monic as $f\mapsto 0$ means $f$ is trivial on $B/\cap_{f\in A'} \ker f$ and so also on $B$; so, $f=0$. But I doubt you can force this to be surjective in all cases.  Maybe there is a theorem that says otherwise, but here is an alternative reason I don't think you can.

If things are over a field $R$ (or if $A$ and $C$ are reflective $R$-modules) you can also shuffle the product to one $\circ:\hom_R(C,R)\times B\to \hom_R(A,R)$, i.e.

$(\lambda\circ b)(a) = \lambda(a*b)$

So perfect would just mean the dual $\hom_R(A,R)\cong B\otimes_R\hom_R(C,R)$.  If $A'$ is any submodule of $\hom_R(A,R)$, it is hard to believe you can always choose $B'$ so that $B\otimes_R \hom_R(C,R)\cong A'$.  E.g. using dimensions just choose an $A'$ of prime dimension coprime to the dimension of $C$.  So perhaps the $B'$ you seek is not always going to exist.